# How to solve the following error of visualforce page "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at bootstrap.min.js:6"?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, bootstrap

We are using bootstrap in our visualforce page for modal popup. And it is working correctly on our browsers. But one user having the issue for loading jQuery.
He is getting error **"Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at bootstrap.min.js:6"** in his console.
[image: Error Image]

We are not getting any solution for this problem. We have searched for the solution and found this link [In this they said to require the jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009070/bootstrap-doesnt-detect-jquery-unless-i-import-it-from-url)
But If I tried this code in my visualforce page then it is giving error like **"uncaught reference error: require is not defined"**.
I am using this code to require jQuery

`<script> window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery'); </script>`

And for css, bootstrap and jQuery loading we are using below code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Please help us out and let me know if you have any questions
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `require()`, you need to include [requirejs](https://requirejs.org/). However, that's apparently not your problem. If it's just one user, check to see if jQuery is 404'ing, what browser they're using, etc. My immediate guesses are that they're on IE 11 or something, or a firewall/antivirus issue. Just to verify, I tested your code in a modern browser and it works fine on my device, so the problem's not the code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have included require.js file in my code and for require error is resolved. And user is using Microsoft edge browser in windows.